# How to get the type and size of the git object using one single command?

Tags: git

Separately I can get type using `git cat-file -t` and size using `git cat-file -s`.

At the same type I can get type and size of all objects inside the tree just using `git ls-tree -l`.

But how can I properly get those for one single object using one single command?

Comment: You probably can’t. Unless you write yourself some program that checks both individually and reports it back at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably no way of doing it on git, but you can do a little shell magic.

`git cat-file -t master ; git cat-file -s master` will work but will output in two lines.

If you want it on one line:

`(git cat-file -t master ; git cat-file -s master) | paste -sd " "`

Comment: Or: `echo $(git cat-file -t $obj) $(git cat-file -s $obj)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second command with piping to `paste` did not work for me though. It seems dash at the end is needed: `(git cat-file -t master ; git cat-file -s master) | paste -sd " " -`

Comment: @skovalyov ah. Then we share the same shell (Bash on ubuntu here), but I think OSX implements many commands a little differently. I guess `paste` could be one of those.